# Adding comments with gem/ Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, comments

I have been learning some RoR and I have just created my first web application, a photosharing site that is basically a Pinterest copy. Now I am trying to add more functionality and I would like if users would be able to comment pins.

I'm using the Commontator Gem: https://github.com/lml/commontator/blob/master/README.md

The only problem is that I don't know where to put `<%= commontator_thread(commontable) %>` 
in my show.html.erb file. I have tried many different places but for some reason it ends up throwing an exception. Here is my show html.erb:

```
<%= link_to 'Back', pins_path %>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading center">
        <%= image_tag @pin.image.url(:medium) %>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p><%= @pin.description %></p>
        <p><strong><%= @pin.user.name if @pin.user %></strong></p>




        <%= link_to edit_pin_path(@pin) do %>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
        Edit


      <% end %>



      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would very much appreciate if someone could tell me where I should put that link.

Thank you!

Comment: It's actual position should be flexible. Are you sure you followed the whole setup of the gem correctly? I am almost certain that it throws an exception due to the missing method you are trying to call.

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue here isn't about where you insert it in your **show.html.erb**. It seems like the model you want to be able to comment on is your **Pin** model. If so, the [documentation](https://github.com/lml/commontator/blob/master/README.md) (under the section **Usage**) indicates that you first need to add `acts_as_commontable` in your **Pin** model.

Then in **show.html.erb**

```
<%= commontator_thread(@pin) %>
```

The `commontable` is a instance of the model that `acts_as_commontable` which I assume here is `@pin`

Comment: Hey, I implemented exactly according to the documentation but it shows Anonymous user and other things works perfectly.