# Add comments to my rails app?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, comments

im trying to add comments to my post in my rails app. but i dont know where to insert `commontator_thread(@commontable)` into my show.html.erb template. please help. below is my code for the show.html.erb.

```
<%= link_to pins_path do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span>  Back
<% end %>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading center">  
            <%= image_tag @pin.image.url(:medium), class: "img-rounded img-polaroid" %>
      </div>
        <div class="panel">
        <p><%= @pin.description %></p>
        <p><strong><%= @pin.user.name if @pin.user %></strong></p>

        <% if @pin.user == current_user %>
         <%= link_to edit_pin_path(@pin) do %>
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit

       <ul class="media-list">
  <li class="media">
    <a class="pull-left" href="#">
      <img class="media-object" src="..." alt="...">
    </a>
    <div class="media-body">
      <h4 class="media-heading">Comments</h4>

    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

     <% end %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Can you explain what `commontator_thread(@commontable)` is and where it comes from? Perhaps post some of code from the controller?

Comment: Check out my answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20459291/adding-comments-with-gem-ruby-on-rails/25027492#25027492) and also @KirtiThorat gave a response to this problem too [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22342512/undefined-local-variable-or-method-error-when-using-commontator-gem-for-commen)

Answer (score 0):

Might want to check out the [acts_as_commentable](https://github.com/jackdempsey/acts_as_commentable) gem as well.  It has been around since rails 2 and is a solid commenting system